# Single query for two database connection on SSP Class PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to retrieve data from 2 database which is from the same server on single query.

So here's query I want to implement.

```
SELECT Customer.id, Receipt.Status,
(SELECT b.created_date FROM systemB.History as b WHERE b.id_number LIKE Customer.id 
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) as Date 
FROM Customer
LEFT JOIN Receipt ON Receipt.Card_No = Customer.id
WHERE Receipt.Status = 'PAID
```

and it give result as below.

```
'+--------+--------+--------------+
|   id    | Status |    Date      |
+---------+--------+--------------+            
|   1     | PAID   |   2023-02-01 |  
|   2     | PAID   |   2022-07-05 |  
+--------+---------+--------------+
```

systemA database for table --> Customer, Receipt

systemB database for table --> History

Basically, both connection on the same server with same username & password. How do I to implement  below query on server_processing.php

```
(SELECT b.created_date FROM systemB.History as b WHERE b.id_number LIKE Customer.id 
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) as Date
```

**server_processing.php**

```
 <?php
    
    $table = 'Customer'; // DB table to use
    
    $primaryKey = 'id'; // Table's primary key
    
    // The `db` parameter represents the column name in the database, while the `dt`
    // parameter represents the DataTables column identifier. In this case simple
    // indexes
    $columns = array(
        array( 'db' => '`c`.`id`',  'dt' => 'id', 'field' => 'id' ),
        array( 'db' => '`r`.`Status`', 'dt' => 'Status', 'field' => 'Status' )
    );
    
    $sql_details = array( ); // sql connection

    require('ssp.customized.class.php' );
    $joinQuery = "FROM `Customer` AS `c` 
                  LEFT JOIN `Receipt` AS `r` ON (`c`.`id` = `r`.`Card_No`)"; 

    $where = "`r`.`Status` = 'PAID'";
    
    echo json_encode(
    SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns, $joinQuery, $where)
); ?>
```

I've been trying like below. It's give me this error.

```
$joinQuery = "FROM `Customer` AS `c` 
              LEFT JOIN `Receipt` AS `r` ON (`c`.`id` = `r`.`Card_No`)
              LEFT JOIN `systemB.History` AS `b` ON (`c`.`id` = `b`.`id_number`)
              ";
```

*An SQL error occurred: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'systemA.systemB.History' doesn't exist*

How to implement the query? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL the backtick is the identifier quote character. This means that anything inside the backticks is treated as one identifier. The backticks are only needed if you have special characters in the indentifier.

In your query you have:

```
`systemB.History`
```

Which means that MySQL is looking for a table `systemB.History` from the current (systemA) database.

You can instead use:

```
systemB.History
```

Or if you want to use backticks, then:

```
`systemB`.`History`
```